# Rtsne function only reading part of my dataset

Tags: r

I am completely new to dealing with high dimensional data. I am currently trying to perform t-SNE in R on my dataset. When I run my code (please see below) the Rtsne function only reads a 30x30 matrix. My data set is 30x72 matrix, with 30 observations (rows) and 72 variables (columns).

```
proclus.tSNE<-Rtsne(mydataset, dims = 2, perplexity=9, verbose=TRUE, max_iter = 5000)
```

I am not sure why the rest of my matrix is not being read. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`mydataset` is a matrix of protein expression values.

Thanks!

Comment: look at the parameter `initial_dims`, 30 by default

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure how to incorporate the `initial_dims` parameter into the code correctly. I tried the following but it still read a 30x30 matrix. `proclus.tSNE<-Rtsne(mydataset, initial_dims= 72, dims = 2, perplexity=9, verbose=TRUE, max_iter = 5000)`. Do you know what I am still doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Quick additional note: I tried transposing my dataset so that there would be more rows than columns and this works (even without initial_dims) Rtsne reads a 72x30 matrix. So why does my actual 30 x72 matrix not get read?

Comment: Try other values for `initial_dims` for the PCA. Don't have time to look at the maths behind but you have more rows than columns ~ variables. For a PCA you are limited by the number of observations